# Does AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation need to be called on the UI thread?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

When I'm inside an asynchronous `Task` can I declare and use an `AsyncOperation` using `AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation()` within the body of the Task itself or must I create the `AsyncOperation` outside the Task in the UI thread?

If I must declare it outside, then this will be inside a view model's ICommand.Execute so can I presume it will always be called on the UI thread?

Comment: The code that creates the AsyncOperation must *run* on the UI thread to get the expected outcome.  That makes it quite unsuitable for Task, you should be using TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext instead.  AsyncOperation was yesterday.

Comment: Is AsyncOperation really outdated compared to TaskScheduler? In the very latest async-await documentation Microsoft mentions AsyncOperationManager should be used for synchronisation. The reason I don't want to use TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext inside a method is because the method itself may not be called from the UI thread, but I want to synchronise to the thread that constructed the entire class (which is guaranteed to be the UI thread).

Comment: It is up to you to pick the flavor of async of the year you prefer.  It is mixing flavors that will get you into trouble.  The point of Task is that you create them on the UI thread and run them later.  If you use AsyncOperationManager in a method that doesn't run on the UI thread then it will misbehave the same way as Task or async, the operation won't run on the UI thread.

Comment: I just found out that AsyncOperation does not have a Send() method either. I want to block the worker thread until the operation completes (It's a MessageBox). I don't want to predefine class wide Tasks for trivial things such as ObservableCollection.Remove() to run on the UI thread. Can I just store the SynchronizationContext.Current in my view model constructor and use that since the view model is constructed on the UI thread? Also what is the difference between the AsyncOperation.SynchronizationContext when it's created on a non-UI thread and just calling new SynchronizationContext()?

Comment: As long as you obtain the value of SynchronizationContext.Current on the UI thread then you're good, storing it is not a problem.  If this is just for a message box then the simple way is to just use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke